# How to style td with input button and text-size button?

Tags: html, css, styling

How to make `<td>` width exactly as input ok button and other input maximum width?And how to set text size of input's `value="Ok"` :

```
<div id="resourcelink">
    <form method="POST" action="FeedController">
        <table id="resource-link">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" id="resourcelink" name="sourceLink" /></td>
                <td><input type="submit" name="linkSub" value="Ok" /></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
</div>
<body>
```

[image]

Css:

```
input#resourcelink {
    width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Start by cleaning up the markup. There are duplicate element IDs. Each ID must be unique per page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `<input type="submit">`, try using a `<button>` element. You'll find that it's easier to apply CSS styles to.

If you apply `boz-sizing: border-box` CSS rules to the form elements, then you can simply give them a width of 100% and they will fill the available space perfectly:

```css
td.wide { width:300px; }
td.narrow { width:100px; }

input[type="text"] {
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding:0.25em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
}
button[type="submit"] {
  font-size:1.5em;
  padding:0.25em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <form>
    <table id="resourcelink">
      <tr>
        <td class="wide"><input type="text" /></td>
        <td class="narrow"><button type="submit">OK</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td style="background-color:#fa0; height:10px;"></td>
        <td style="background-color:#46f; height:10px;"></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2">(The coloured bars are just here to
                        illustrate the column sizes.)</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
<body>
```

(Note: `border-box` rules are [supported in all modern browsers](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp), but if you want to support older browsers then  you'll have to include workarounds.)